# Heroku - Binary only buildack?

Tags: heroku, playframework, binary, playframework-2.1, procfile

I'm attempting to upload a Play! 2.1 Project to Heroku, however the build keeps timing out after 15 minutes. (During the javascript minification/uglification stage).

Plan B is to simply compile it ourselves locally (`play dist`) and upload the resulting compiled package with a Procfile to launch it.

This fails, however, as Heroku seems intent on detecting source code and compiling it, and doesn't seem to be happy with executing a simple shell script.

```
Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
```

Is it possible to have heroku ignore the build process and simply execute my Procfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to push your zip file into a git repo, and then you'll have to use a special buildpack, and a special Procfile.

Maybe it can help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16580332/320180